# How to bind Data to usercontrol without constructor?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have used the user control from this link https://www.codeproject.com/articles/739902/how-to-easily-host-wpf-control-inside-windows-form
I am Only Able to Load Data in this user control in Constructor But I want to call it from other method but I failed Is there any Way?
The construcor is

```
public Getstarted()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   List<Employee2> employees = new List<Employee2>();
   try
   {
       con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
       con.Open();
       cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Participant.ParticipantName, MeetingParticipant.Title, Participant.ParticipantId FROM            MeetingParticipant INNER JOIN Participant ON MeetingParticipant.ParticipantId = Participant.ParticipantId INNER JOIN Meeting ON MeetingParticipant.MeetingId = Meeting.MeetingId where Meeting.Statuss='Open'", con);
       rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            while (rdr.Read() == true)
            {
                employees.Add(new Employee2() { Name = rdr[0].ToString(), Title = rdr[1].ToString(), Id = rdr[2].ToString()});
            }
            con.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
   this.comboBoxWithGrid_WinformsHost1.Employee2s = employees;
}
```

I Have Tried this on Button Event but Failed

```
private void MyMethod()
{       
    List<Employee2> employees = new List<Employee2>();
    try
    {
       con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
       con.Open();
       cmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT Participant.ParticipantName, MeetingParticipant.Title, 
       Participant.ParticipantId FROM            MeetingParticipant 
           INNER JOIN 
             Participant ON MeetingParticipant.ParticipantId = 
             Participant.ParticipantId INNER JOIN Meeting ON 
             MeetingParticipant.MeetingId = Meeting.MeetingId where 
             Meeting.Statuss='Open'", con);
      rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

      while (rdr.Read() == true)
      {
          employees.Add(new Employee2() { Name = rdr[0].ToString(), Title = rdr[1].ToString(), Id = rdr[2].ToString()});     
      }
      con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     }
        this.comboBoxWithGrid_WinformsHost1.Employee2s = employees;
}
```

This is my First question Here And I am Novice In this Sector If Something missing Please try to understand My limitation Thank you.

Comment: It is generally considered the standard to provide any error messages or description of errors instead of saying "it failed".

Comment: I did not got any error message.

Comment: Then remember to include the difference between what should happen and what did happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Direct answer to my problem  but I solved my issue by 
using this line

```
        this.comboBoxWithGrid_WinformsHost1.Employee2s.AddRange(employees);
```